# MUI-Datatables Using Autocomplete as Custom Filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm trying to use the Material-UI Autocomplete field inside filters of MUI-Datatables. Visually is working, I can select the options, but at the moment that I apply the filter, it crash with the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js:241
  238 | }) : [];
  239 | 
  240 | if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
> 241 |   if (value !== null && !freeSolo && options.length > 0) {
      | ^  242 |     var missingValue = (multiple ? value : [value]).filter(function (value2) {
  243 |       return !options.some(function (option) {
  244 |         return getOptionSelected(option, value2);
```

This is the code that I use in the column settings:

```
{
      name: "marca",
      label: "Marca",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        filterType: "custom",
        sortThirdClickReset: true,
        customFilterListOptions: {
          render: (v) => `Marca: ${v}`,
        },
        filterOptions: {
          display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
            return (
              <Autocomplete
                disableClearable
                getOptionLabel={(status) => status.marca}
                options={info.filters.marcas}
                noOptionsText={"No se encontraron resultados"}
                defaultValue={
                  filterList[5].length > 0
                    ? { marca: filterList[5][0] }
                    : { marca: "Todos" }
                }
                onChange={(event, value) => {
                  filterList[index] = [value.marca]
                  onChange(filterList[index], index, column)
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextFieldMaterial
                    {...params}
                    fullWidth
                    margin="normal"
                    label="Marcas"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              />
            )
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

Using standard options works fine and filters okey, but there are so many options thats lags the selector.

I'm algo struggling to make it "API friendly", because I need to filter like &marca=1 and it tries to filter as &marca=FORD, cause MUI-Datatables can't (or I don't know) how to manipulate value and label for table data and filters

Comment: Can you show how `info` defined/modified? And also put `console.log('info', info)` in the `display` callback and show all output (on success and on error)

Comment: @wowandy ```info``` is what it comes from API request, at the time, is reloaded in the moment when filters are applyed, but the new data incoming is the same ```info.filters``` is reloaded, but not changed.
When I sort of search, table is reloaded and  ```info.filters```  too, but no error

Comment: definitely it's a problem of the options, since info at some point is undefined, its crashes, but, with a ternary operator can't get if working, any idea?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example or at least component code